# Post a photo with text from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'd like to post picture + text from my app.
What I do at the moment - I just post photo to the user's album. But There is no link to my app, I cannot see it etc.. I'd like to have mentioning my Facebook page in the text with photo, so I'll receive notifications. Or at least link to my website, so people who likes the post can go there.

Ideal way is how Runkeeper does it:
[image: Runkeeper Screenshot]

I like that it has link RunKeeper, small icon of RunKeeper in the bottom with link to their website too.

Alternatively I'd be happy to post photo with text and link to my facebook page or external page.
Something like that:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

That's pretty simple to do with [Facebook's SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/).

You will need to set up an app in Facebook to link to your phone app, there you can use your icon and link.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *postParams = @{ @"message" : <#Your Message#>,
                                      @"app_id" : <#Your AppId#>,
                                      @"picture" : <#Your Image#>,
                                      @"link" : <#Your App Link#>,
                                      @"name" : <#Your App Name#>,
                                      @"caption" : <#Your Caption#>,
                                      @"description" : <#Your Description#>
                                   };


[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:self.session parameters:postParams handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
      <#Your Completion handler#>}
```

Comment: the text can be added when you post the image

Comment: This doesnt answer the question. Saying use the SDK only gives the first step which is the easiest.